# sagepay not working when two items in cart

Tags: php, opayo

When I have an item added in the cart it works fine. However when I add two items It doesn't work. I get error 3021 Error in format.`                      require_once ('SagePay/lib/SagePay.php');

```
$sagePay = new SagePay();
$sagePay->setCurrency('GBP');
$sagePay->setAmount($item_total);
$sagePay->setDescription("Bates Environmental Ltd");
$sagePay->setBillingSurname($user['Surname']);
$sagePay->setBillingFirstnames($user['FirstName']);
$sagePay->setBillingCity($user['BillingAddressCity']);
$sagePay->setBillingPostCode($user['BillingAddressPostCode']);
$sagePay->setBillingAddress1($user['BillingAddressLine1']);
$sagePay->setBillingCountry('GB');
$sagePay->setDeliverySameAsBilling();
```

Comment: What's your code when you're adding multiple items?

Comment: foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {

                        $descriptionNode = $xml->createElement('description');
                        $descriptionNode->nodeValue = $item["ProductName"];
                        $itemNode->appendChild($descriptionNode);